# State update of objects in array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, react-state

Based on the code below, setCaptured only updates for one object at a time. So, for example, I click on Bulbasaur and capturedPkm will contain Bulbasaur, but then I click on Ivisaur and capturedPkm will contain Ivisaur only and not also Bulbasaur. How can I make it so that capturedPkm will receive all the Pokemons I have captured? Thanks!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PokemonIcon from './PokemonIcon';

const PokemonCard = (props) => {
    const { url } = props
    const URL = url
    const [pokemonCard, setPokemonCard] = useState([])
    const [captured, setCaptured] = useState({})
    const [capturedPkm, setCapturedPkm] = useState([])
    const [notCapturedPkm, setNotCapturedPkm] = useState([])


    const toggleCaptured = (checked, id) => {
        const currentChecked = { ...captured };
        // let capturedPkm = [];
        // let notCapturedPkm = [];
        console.log(id)
        if (checked) {
            currentChecked[pokemonCard.name] = true;
            capturedPkm.push(currentChecked)
        } else {
            notCapturedPkm.push(pokemonCard.name)
            delete currentChecked[pokemonCard.name]
            capturedPkm.slice(0, 1)
        }

        setCaptured(currentChecked);
        setCapturedPkm(...capturedPkm, currentChecked)
        setNotCapturedPkm(...notCapturedPkm, currentChecked)
        console.log(currentChecked);

        console.log('captured', capturedPkm, 'not captured', notCapturedPkm)
    }

    const fetchingPokemonCard = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(URL);
        const data = await res.json();
        //console.log(data)
        setPokemonCard(data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchingPokemonCard()
    }, [URL])

    return (
        <>
            <div className='pokemon-card' style={{
                height: '250px',
                maxWidth: '250px',
                margin: '1rem',
                boxShadow: '5px 5px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
                cursor: 'pointer',
            }} >
                <Link
                    to={{ pathname: `/pokemon/${pokemonCard.id}` }}
                    state={{ pokemon: pokemonCard, captured }}
                    style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: '#000000' }}>
                    <div
                        style={{ padding: '20px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }} >
                        <PokemonIcon img={pokemonCard.sprites?.['front_default']} />
                    </div>
                </Link>
                <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                    <h1 >{pokemonCard.name}</h1>
                    <label >
                        <input
                            type='checkbox'
                            defaultChecked={false}
                            onChange={(e) => toggleCaptured(e.target.checked, pokemonCard.id)}
                        />
                        <span style={{ marginLeft: 8, cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                            {captured[pokemonCard.name] ? 'Captured!' : 'Not captured!'}
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default PokemonCard
```

Answer (score 0):

In the way you structured your code, every time you call the `toggleCaptured` function, you recreate the variable `capturedPkm`.
Instead, if you want that the variable contains all the pokemon for different interation, you may have to create a state

```
const [capturedPkm, setCapturedPkm] = useState([]);
```

and every time you can update it adding new element

```
setCapturedPkm(...capturedPkm, currentChecked);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I've edited my post to show the changes I've made based on what you said, but now it seems like I can't push anything in capturedPkm or notCapturedPkm because 'they're not a function'. That's the error I'm getting. Why?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, to update them you have to do `setCapturedPkm(...capturedPkm, newPokemon);`  where `newPokemon` is the new value and don't use `push`

Comment: Sure but newPokemon is defined nowhere, that's why I used currentChecked. 'Don't use push' seems pretty useless as a reply. Why can't I use it?

Comment: Sorry, with `newPokemon` I indicate your `currenctChecked` variable. You can't use `push` because you're working with a state that is a `React Hook` and it has its method `useState`. Only in this way you can update it correctly.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. Even like this though, I keep getting only one pokemon in the capturedPkm array. Plus, if I try to delete it from capturedPkm and push it to notCapturedPkm, I get 'object is not iterable'.